# VBA - IF loop improvements

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I'm currently running a macro which identifies duplicates in a workbook, however it identifies the first set off the index and doesn't tag the first set then which has led to me setting up a if statement to by pass this, which adds duplicate to the first instance too. This is taking a long time to do however and would like to improve this, if possible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I am new to VBA but have been learning bits as I've encountered new problems!

```
'Declaring the lastRow variable as Long to store the last row value in the Column1
Dim lastRow As Long
'matchFoundIndex is to store the match index values of the given value
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
'iCntr is to loop through all the records in the column 1 using For loop
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim first_dup As Long
    Dim tagging As Long
    Dim item_code As String

'Finding the last row in the Column 1
    lastRow = Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row
'
'looping through the column1
    For iCntr = 2 To lastRow

        'checking if the cell is having any item, skipping if it is blank.
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
             'getting match index number for the value of the cell

             matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)

            'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
            If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then

                'Printing the label in the column B
                Cells(iCntr, 4) = "Duplicate"

            End If
        End If
    Next


   For first_dup = 2 To lastRow
      If Cells(first_dup, 5) = "Duplicate" Then
          item_code = Cells(first_dup, 1)
          For tagging = 2 To lastRow
              If Cells(tagging, 1) = item_code Then
                   Cells(tagging, 5) = "Duplicate"
              End If
          Next
       End If
   Next

Example data:
item code   
1   
2   
3   
4   
1   duplicate
2   duplicate
3   duplicate
4   duplicate
1   duplicate
2   duplicate
3   duplicate
4   duplicate
```

Comment: Iterating over the Range.Value array instead of using individual Range/Cell should help. You can also get the same result using a formula `=IF(MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0)<>ROW($A2), "Duplicate", "")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is not to over-complicate things, try using duplicate values conditional formatting to see if this helps:

[image]

Failing that, if you are desperate to find ONLY the duplicates, and not the first occurrence, you can use a formula like this: (In Cell B2 if your Data starts in A2, it will require a header row that doesn't match, or your first row will always match)

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:A$1,A2)>=1,"Duplicate","")
```

Which when pasted down your row of data could look something like this:

[image]

There are also VBA solutions if you are desperate for a VBA solution, but I thought I'd give you the simple ones first. Let me know how you get on in the comments.

**Edit**: you can just insert the above formula using VBA, with R1C1 notation, e.g.:

```
Sub test()
    Range("B2:B" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R1C1:R[-1]C1,RC1)>=1,""Duplicate"","""")"
End Sub
```

I'll break this down so you know what is happening.

`Range("B2:B" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)` selects the cells in column B between B2 and the last filled row in column A i.e. `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` (so this won't work if you expect blanks in column A as part of your data)

Then, it sets the R1C1 ref formula to `"=IF(COUNTIF(R1C1:R[-1]C1,RC1)>=1,""Duplicate"","""")"`, where `R1C1` means first row, first column, (i.e. `$A$1`) 
`R[-1]C1` means previous row, first column. For example,
If you are in B5, this would select A4. 
If you are in A2, this would select A1.
If you are in A1, this would error out because you cant be in a row earlier than 1.
And `RC1` means current row, first column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am desperate to find all duplicates, but it needs to flag them all with the "duplicate" tag, as I do further processing to see which categories the duplicates lay in. This needs to be a vba solution as I won't actually be running this going forward and the others won't know how to find the duplicates. Thanks for your suggestions on excel first though! Ged

Comment: Hi again Andrew, I'm just trying out your suggestion now although the countif does take a long time I think it'll work better than the loops I was doing previously. I initially designed the loop as nothing seems to tag all of the duplicates which is what I need. I use this further down the line to find which item lists overlap with one another . Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, could you mark this as answered please?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the same as the initial code I presented, it's taking roughly 5 minutes for 30000 items so it isn't too bad at what it does.